# Codename One - iOS publishing

Tags: ios, codenameone, release

Here is the way to my problem:

1. **Developed** *Codename One* application.
2. **Enrolled** Apple Developer Program.
3. Made **release build** to .ipa file.
4. **Filled** all required information at *itunesconnect*
5. Now is the question: **how to upload .ipa to itunesconnect without Mac**?

I did not find anything in the search engines about this.

Comment: You will need access to a Mac

Comment: how to upload .ipa to itunesconnect without Mac ? You can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need access to a Mac in order to deliver your app to the App Store using the Application Loader. From the [Codename One FAQ](https://www.codenameone.com/faq.html):

> The only place where you still need a Mac at this time is for store upload which at this time requires the Application Loader tool that is only available on a Mac.

Comment: Also notice you can use Mac In Cloud which has (or used to have) a free trial quota that was enough for an upload of this type. Ideally in the future we'll also address that "last mile" problem and do the upload for developers

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this out: https://wenz.io/ApplicationLoader
Works amazing well. Costs $1.49 per upload and needs you to enter your apple id credentials. Works in a minute or so and a successful upload sends you an email from them and an email from apple.

Comment: easy way to compromise developer account